# for-loop inside switch statement

Tags: c++, for-loop, switch-statement, duffs-device

I was converting a c++ [code](https://github.com/jaredks/pyprimesieve/blob/master/primesieve/src/EratSmall.cpp#L78) I found over the internet to javascript, and I was perplexed to see the following statement:

```
switch(wheelIndex) {
  for(;;) {  //<--------
    case 0:
      ...
    case 1:
      ...
  }
  break;
  for(;;) {
    ...
```

What does `for(;;)` inside `switch` mean?

Comment: Is there a break hiding inside that for-loop?

Comment: C.f. [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) (maybe).

Comment: See [Duff's_device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)

Comment: There is a break inside each cases (in a if statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very old (dirty) C trick commonly referred as [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).
The idea is that the switch let you jump at a some place **inside** a loop.

So basically you have a loop but you can start it at some defined points (the cases), that on the value `wheelIndex`.

The loop itself is an infinite loop (no initialization, no test, no increment). This kind of loop can be broken by the use of some `goto`, `break` or `return`.